# Creating Excel formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formatting

I'm creating a VLOOKUP formula in VBA.  The formula works fine in my spreadsheet, but when I try to automate it in VBA, I'm getting an @' in the formula.

Here's the line in the Macro:

```
Range("B" & intUserRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(TEXT(A" & intUserRow & "," & vbDoubleQuote & "0" & vbDoubleQuote & "),UserNames!A1:B166,2)"
```

Adding a Watch in VBA, it shows me this:

```
"=VLOOKUP(TEXT(A7,"0"),UserNames!A1:B166,2)"
```

But in Excel, the formula ends up with an @ and a single quote in it:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(@'A7',"0"),UserNames!'A1':'B166',2)
```

Where is that @' coming from? I briefly saw a pop-up saying something like "Where is there an @ in my formula?" but the pop-up disappeared before I could read it.
I assume there's some formatting Excel doesn't like, but it looks correct to me in the Watch window.

Comment: Just realized there's another single quote after the A6, too

Comment: try `.Fomula` not `.FormulaR1C1`

Comment: What's the value in A7 and can you include the formula as typed in Excel.

Comment: Found the answer!
I was mixing my cell notation.
Using FormulaR1C1 = but specifying the Cell values as A7
I changed to Formula = and it's working now.

Comment: Enlighten us.  Please self answer with what you found,  it may help future readers

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating an Excel Formula in VBA it's always a smart move to first create it in the Excel spreadsheet while recording a macro, VBA will create the code for your formula and you can use it as is, or adapt it to your needs.

In this case I belive that you need to use RC cells notation for your cells references, for example:

If you are puting the formula in the "B1" cell then instead of using "A1" you use R[0]C[-1] wich means "from B1 move 0 rows and 1 column to the left"

An absolute reference like $A$1:$B$166 would be: R1C1:R166C2

Give this code a try:

```
Range("B" & intUserRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(TEXT(RC[-1],""0""),UserNames!R1C1:R166C2,2,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said:
Found the answer! I was mixing my cell notation.
I was Using
Formula***R1C1*** =
however, I was specifying the Cell values as A7
I changed to
Formula =
and it's working now.
Original:
Range("B" & intUserRow).Formula***R1C1*** = "=VLOOKUP(TEXT(A" & intUserRow & "," & vbDoubleQuote & "0" & vbDoubleQuote & "),UserNames!A1:B166,2)"
Corrected version:
Range("B" & intUserRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(TEXT(A" & intUserRow & "," & vbDoubleQuote & "0" & vbDoubleQuote & "),UserNames!A1:B166,2)"